# Attaching Asterisk console to process

Tags: asterisk

I want to open control console on currently running Asterisk instance. When am I supposed to use option `-r` and when `-c` in order to connect to Asterisk process?

What is a main difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-r is for a "running" Asterisk instance that you wish to connect to.  When you exit the connection, Asterisk continues to run in the background.

-c is for starting up Asterisk in "foreground / console" mode.  As soon as you exit that console, Asterisk shuts down.

*As always, if this response answers your question, please 'accept' it for the benefit of others in the future with the same question. Thanks.*

Comment: Now I think I'm beginning to glimpse how this is works. Also, I figured out, that in order to attach to running instatance it's necessary to use `-R` option.